# Inject Groovy into existing Maven Java Project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, groovy

I have been maintaining a maven java project for year.
Recently, I learned Ruby and asked why haven't these nice features (of Ruby) existed in Java, and I am so happy to find Groovy the answer. It's already out there for more than 6 years and what a shame I didn't know about it sooner.
Now come to the story:
I have a lot of java code written already, organized in folder structures follow maven default convention (`src/main/java` for logic & `src/test/java` for test)

Now, I want to write some new stuff in Groovy, so I guess I should create `src/main/groovy` for groovy logic and `src/test/groovy` for test. However, both `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and the latest `m2eclipse` only understand and include `src/main/groovy` as source code folder of the generated eclipse project, and don't not recognize `src/test/groovy` at all.

Is this the correct behavior? Or am I missed any thing?

By the way, here is the gmaven plugin configured inside my POM:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-1.7</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <providerSelection>1.7</providerSelection>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find that you have better luck with new version of m2eclipse instead of eclipse:eclipse.  Either way, once your project is in eclipse, navigate your src/{main,test}/ folder, right-click and choose Build Path and "User as Source Folder".

Answer (score 0):

Using eclipse can be more comfortable : 
Import your project into eclipse as "Maven project" 
1) go to Eclipse Marketplace & install groovy compiler
[image: 1) go to Eclipse Marketplace & install groovy compiler]

2)right-click on project and configure it as groovy project [image: right-click on project and configure it as groovy project]

3)result :
[image: 3)result :]